# Adding option table value on activation of theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-theme

hi i want to add option table value empty to empty while enabling theme. i tried below code. it doen't add value.

In functions.php

```
function Arion_register() {
    add_option("arion_site_logo","");
}
add_action('switch_theme', 'Arion_register');
```

I want to add option table value to empty while activating theme.

Comment: With `add_option` you can not change existing option. The codex says: « Existing options will not be updated »: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_option/

Comment: You better use `update_option`.